# How do i return the last generated number in a for loop?

Tags: java, function, return

How do i get the last generated number of a for loop?

So after maybe 10 times i want to return this number but it says:
This method must return a result of type float.
When i try to fit it (adding a return statement) it does not work at all...

```
package test;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        plus();
    }

    public static float plus() {
        float a = 13.6f;
        float t = 1;
        float c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            c = (a * t + c);
            if (i == 9) {
                return (float) (c);

            }
        }
        System.out.println(c);

    }
}
```

This method must return a result of type float.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Move the `return` to where the `System.out.println(c);` statement is
`

Comment: If you return inside the `for` loop, you'll never execute the `println()` after it.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that the function does not end with a return statement.

Comment: BTW, there's no need for a loop. The result is just `10 * a * t`

Comment: And hint: `return (float) c` ... that cast to float is really pointless here, as c is declared as float. This is rather confusing your readers. Avoid doing that. Also consider to use more than one character for variable names. Your names tell the reader what is going on. a, b, c ... only tell me that the author doesn't consider readability of code ;-)

Comment: Maybe it needs to return in all control sequences? I think that `return .0` on the end should do the trick...?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
System.out.println(c);
```

The fact that you put that statement *after* the loop body already indicates that you can envision that maybe, your loop doesn't always end by *returning* the whole method within the loop body.

The compiler doessn't know either (it could, but in Java, the compiler is pretty dumb and ignores such knowledge).

Thus: you have to make sure that there is a return statement on **all** paths that can be taken.

Right now, you only cover a path within that for loop. But what if that loop is never taken, or ends without reaching the return?!

Thus: simply add a return in the end.

Ideally, you simply return `c` and you remove the if+return from the loop body. You want to return after the last loop iteration, so simply put your return **after** the loop body!

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the if-statement in the loop, since it's going to stop anyways at i==9.

```
public static float plus() {
    float a = 13.6f;
    float t = 1;
    float c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        c = (a * t + c);
        }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.*;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float result = Test2.plus();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static float plus() {
        float a = 13.6f;
        float t = 1;
        float c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            c = (a * t + c);
            if (i == 9) {
                return (float) (c);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it really helped. :D